# Семантика слова "бедный"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, история

Кого ранее называли бедным человеком? Исходя из представленного ниже контекста это человек без рук?

Евангелие от Марка:

И аще съблажняетъ тя **рука** твоа, отъсеци ю. добре ти есть **беднику** въ животъ внити, неже обе руце имущу внити въ геену

Аще ли **рука** твоа или нога твоа съблажняетъ тя. отъсеци ю, и врьзи отъ себе. добреише ти есть внити в животъ хрому, или **бедну**.

Где-то читал, что ранее побежденных вроде лишали большого пальца, чтобы они в будущем больше никогда не смогли вновь взяться за меч, может это как-то связано?

Comment: просьба к тем, кто жмет минус, оставлять комментарии. Ваше мнение ценно.

Answer (score 2):

Верно, согласно Полному церковнославянскому словарю

> **бедник**, **бѣдный** — калека, безрукий

В Синодальном переводе это слово перевели как *увечный*:

> И если соблазняет тебя рука твоя, отсеки ее: лучше тебе **увечному** войти в жизнь, нежели с двумя руками идти в геенну, в огонь неугасимый *(Св. Евангелие от Матфея 9:43)*

и *лишённый руки*:

> Если же рука твоя или нога твоя соблазняет тебя, отсеки их и брось от себя: лучше тебе войти в жизнь **без руки** или без ноги, нежели с двумя руками и с двумя ногами быть ввержену в огонь вечный… *(Св. Евангелие от Матфея 18:8)*